# getting the error of RuntimeError: Unsupported image type, must be 8bit gray or RGB image

Tags: python

the face recognition code

```
import face_recognition
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os


def Recognizer(details):
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    known_face_encodings = []
    known_face_names = []

    # base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    # image_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, "static")
    # image_dir = os.path.join(image_dir, "profile_pics")

    # base_dir = os.getcwd()
    base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    # os.chdir("..")
    base_dir = os.getcwd()
    image_dir = os.path.join(base_dir,"{}\{}\{}\{}\{}\{}".format('static','images','Student_Images',details['branch'],details['year'],details['section']))
    # print(image_dir)
    names = []


    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(image_dir):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('jpg') or file.endswith('png'):
                path = os.path.join(root, file)
                img = face_recognition.load_image_file(path)
                label = file[:len(file)-4]
                img_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
                known_face_names.append(label)
                known_face_encodings.append(img_encoding)

    face_locations = []
    face_encodings = []


    while True: 
    
        check, frame = video.read()
        small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy= 0.5)
        rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:,:,::-1]

        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)
        face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame.repeat(3,2), face_locations)
        face_names = []


        for face_encoding in face_encodings:

            matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, np.array(face_encoding), tolerance = 0.6)

            face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(known_face_encodings,face_encoding) 
            
            try:
                matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, np.array(face_encoding), tolerance = 0.6)

                face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(known_face_encodings,face_encoding)
                best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)

                if matches[best_match_index]:
                    name = known_face_names[best_match_index]
                    face_names.append(name)
                    if name not in names:
                        names.append(name)
            except:
                pass

        if len(face_names) == 0:
            for (top,right,bottom,left) in face_locations:
                top*=2
                right*=2
                bottom*=2
                left*=2

                cv2.rectangle(frame, (left,top),(right,bottom), (0,0,255), 2)

                # cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 30), (right,bottom - 30), (0,255,0), -1)
                font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
                cv2.putText(frame, 'Unknown', (left, top), font, 0.8, (255,255,255),1)
        else:
            for (top,right,bottom,left), name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
                top*=2
                right*=2
                bottom*=2
                left*=2

                cv2.rectangle(frame, (left,top),(right,bottom), (0,255,0), 2)

                # cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 30), (right,bottom - 30), (0,255,0), -1)
                font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
                cv2.putText(frame, name, (left, top), font, 0.8, (255,255,255),1)

        cv2.imshow("Face Recognition Panel",frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('s'):
            break

    video.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return names
```

this dataset linking code

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def takeAttendence(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        details = {
            'branch': request.POST['branch'],
            'year': request.POST['year'],
            'section': request.POST['section'],
            'period': request.POST['period'],
            'faculty': request.user.faculty
        }
        if Attendence.objects.filter(date=str(date.today()), branch=details['branch'], year=details['year'], section=details['section'], period=details['period']).count() != 0:
            messages.error(request, "Attendence already recorded.")
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            students = Student.objects.filter(branch=details['branch'], year=details['year'], section=details['section'])
            names = Recognizer(details)
            for student in students:
                attendence = Attendence(Faculty_Name=request.user.faculty, 
                                        Student_ID=str(student.registration_id), 
                                        period=details['period'], 
                                        branch=details['branch'], 
                                        year=details['year'], 
                                        section=details['section'],
                                        status='Present' if str(student.registration_id) in names else '')
                attendence.save()
            attendences = Attendence.objects.filter(date=str(date.today()), branch=details['branch'], year=details['year'], section=details['section'], period=details['period'])
            context = {"attendences": attendences, "ta": True}
            messages.success(request, "Attendence taking Success")
            return render(request, 'attendence_sys/attendence.html', context)
    return render(request, 'attendence_sys/home.html', {})
```

i am trying but not getting solution can you help me with the error
and how to minimize the

```
students = Student.objects.filter(branch=details['branch'], year=details['year'], section=details['section'])
            names = Recognizer(details)
```

the real problem lies in here

Comment: OpenCV usually loads images as BGR by default (in this case, at `video.read()`), so you will have to convert it to a supported colorspace before feeding it to the actual face recognition.